# kotlin android problem on animation loading in lottie

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

i want load animation from `json` file ... and `json` file is in assets ..
i'm facing this problem

```
binding.animationView.setAnimation(assets.open("failanimation.json"))
```

compiler showing red line on `setAnimation`

Answer (score 0):

Try this once-

> Step 1 -Add your Lottie animation file in **raw resource folder**  app
>
> > res > right-click > New > Folder > Raw Resource Folder

Step 2- XML code

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animationView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"  />
```

Step 3 -

```
binding.animationView.setAnimation(R.raw.failanimation)
```

Comment: Thanks brother this worked ... i randomly tried it

Answer (score -1):

.json file it should be under app/src/main/assets/ folder and
no need to `asset.open`
simply put `setAnimation(json_filename)` in your case it should be `setAnimation("failanimation.json")`

Comment: brother before upper  i used it too but app crashed

Comment: can you post crash log here?